# Build fails when using rent_exempt = skip in account initialization

Tags: anchor, rent

I want to skip rent exemption when initializing PDA account with anchor. Sol will be transfer to PDA right after initialization so there is no need to pay extra sol for rent when PDA is initialized. My build fails when `rent_exempt = skip` option is used in `Accounts` macro.

Code:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Init<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = user,
        space = Vault::MAX_SIZE,
        rent_exempt = skip,
        seeds = [
            b"vault".as_ref(),
            user.key().as_ref()
        ],
        bump
    )]
    pub vault: Account<'info, Vault>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Error:

```
cannot find value `__anchor_rent` in this scope
#[derive(Accounts)]
    |          ^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
    |
    = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Accounts` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "dapp"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "dapp"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
default = []
init_if_needed = []

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = {version = "0.25.0", features = ["init-if-needed"]}
anchor-spl = "0.25.0"
solana-program = "~1.10.29"
bytemuck = "1.7.2"
num-traits = "0.2"
num-derive = "0.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need to add the `zero` constraint, ie:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Init<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        zero,
        init_if_needed,
        payer = user,
        space = Vault::MAX_SIZE,
        rent_exempt = skip,
        seeds = [
            b"vault".as_ref(),
            user.key().as_ref()
        ],
        bump
    )]
    pub vault: Account<'info, Vault>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Know that all accounts must be rent-exempt in order to persist after the transaction, but if you don't need it afterwards, `zero` and `rent_exempt = skip` can be used.

Comment: when `zero` is used it throws another error:
`error: zeroed already provided 
    |
115 |         init_if_needed,
`